# causal graphs in non-linear physics

Tags: causality, graph-neural-network

Can we learn emergent non-linear physics using causal graphs?

Causal graphs are well used in linear systems, I'm wondering if it's too risky to use the approach for non-linear dynamics, such as turbulence in fluids.

Thanks,

Comment: In principle yes, but this question may be too broad for CV.SE's format. I will briefly indulge in a lengthy comment on something I did myself a while back: Take a non-linear (but simple) physics simulation, and collect a sampling of points from it. Then perform structural learning on the data, and see how far off the estimated model is from the ground truth. Repeat a bunch of times to estimate the probability of reconstructing the correct causal structure.

Comment: @Galen, this i exactly what I'm doing, I use an unsupervised framework to capture the keypoints, then use a GNN to capture the causality, however, I find it hard to be completely convinced of the approach, since the pattern change completely in a turbulent flow

Comment: It sounds like you can answer your question. If the correct causal structure is not being reliably reconstructed for a specific system, then such reconstructions are not universally reliable.

Comment: An additional thought or two: Turbulence relates to chaos and stability. Perhaps if you can estimate the Lyapunov stability of a system, then perhaps you can further relate the stability of the system to the reliability with which the causal structure can be inferred.

Comment: I'm really confused by the terminology and seeming lack of focus in this question. As per site rules and suggestions, good questions have a lazer focus. But this has the issue of some undefined terms, and a short and terse presentation that doesn't help clear anything up. Maybe I'm not in-the-know here.

Comment: @AdamO There is some implicit understanding of certain dynamical systems and causal modelling going on here, but I agree that this question is more terse than our site rules and suggestions would recommend.

Comment: I would agree with the comments so far: this is a good question per se, but not a good question for stats.se. I absolutely think that physics can benefit from causal analysis. In fact, I think the New Causal Revolution ought to be part of a required statistics course for all physics majors. Unfortunately, I don't know of any intro stats books that include causality - whereas the basics of causality could absolutely be included in an intro stats course.